# My if else loop for an input doesn't work and I don't know why

Tags: python

```
choice_five = (input("(1) fire ball  (2) cast cloak  "))

if choice_five == "1":
    print("you start up your fire ball and nod at Draco. you both start to advance down the path.")
    print("you turn the corner and stare face to face with two cloaked figures. they react with out hesitation.")
    print("one of the cloaks throws a dark orb of energy at Draco. he swings his axe at it, but it has no effect.")
    print("Draco flys backwards and slams into a tree. you throw your fire ball at the cloak, bu twhen it nears he seems to absorb it.")
    print("a second to late you see the second orb flying at you. you sucumb to the tearing pain and die.")

    restart_one = (input("would you like to try that again? "))

    if restart_one == "yes":
        choice_five
    else:
        print("then stay dead.")
```

my restart command works fine, but it wont run the second question five... can I get some help.

Comment: What should happen if restart_one == yes?

Comment: ah you think that `choice_five` alone on the line will _call_ input again. No it doesn't work that way

Comment: It looks like you are expecting `choice_five` to re-run `input("(1)...")`, which it won't, `choice_five` is bound to the value that's returned from the `input` expression. So `choice_five` is just a string

Comment: ok... how would I go about restarting that input?

Comment: @CYANPATTERSON Maybe with something that is a loop. I don't know where you got the idea that `if` starts a loop, but it doesn't. A `while True:` could be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You may reach your goal with `while` loop. `while` loop in your case iterates over the loop. I also added `pass` statement after the nested `if` loop so that if your answer equals to `yes`, it passes and goes to the first line again:

```
while True:
    choice_five = (input("(1) fire ball  (2) cast cloak  "))
    if choice_five == "1":
        print("you start up your fire ball and nod at Draco. you both start to advance down the path.")
        print("you turn the corner and stare face to face with two cloaked figures. they react with out hesitation.")
        print("one of the cloaks throws a dark orb of energy at Draco. he swings his axe at it, but it has no effect.")
        print("Draco flys backwards and slams into a tree. you throw your fire ball at the cloak, bu twhen it nears he seems to absorb it.")
        print("a second to late you see the second orb flying at you. you sucumb to the tearing pain and die.")

        restart_one = (input("would you like to try that again? "))

        if restart_one == "yes":
            pass
        else:
            print("then stay dead.")
            break
```

Have Fun :)